# Best way to create a server that can be hosted on, and joined by iOS and Android devices

Tags: android, ios, server, client, multiplayer

I'm trying to make a multiplayer racing game where a server can be hosted by a device running either iOS or Android, and joined by either iOS or Android devices.

I don't want to have a server running on another device (e.g. a laptop or dekstop) or a dedicated server, as I want this game to work when users don't have Internet connectivity.

What I plan to do is use the server device's WiFi hotspot to allow other devices to join and communicate with each other. I did investigate bluetooth, but as far as I know, only one device can pair to another at a time?

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375424/can-i-run-an-http-server-on-a-mobile-platform. You may find some useful pointers

Comment: 'I plan to do is use the server device's WiFi hotspot to allow other devices to join and communicate with each other.'. Good idea. Then why do you start talking about bluetooth?