# How to play .m3u8 or .ts file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

I have create one `iOS` application in `xCode 4.5.1`.

The main purpose of this applciation is the playing `.m3u8` video file.

I have add one .m3u8 file with all segment(.ts) in our local resource bundle.
So, how to play this file in iPhone locally using `MPMoviePlayerController` or `UIWebView`?

And, Can we modify or not this file after the download from the server?

If possible then how to do it?

pls tell me, any one known...

Comment: m3u8 is just UTF-8 Plaintext. Nobody will stop you from modifying it.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665151/mpmovieplayercontroller-m3u8-playlist

Comment: Is it possible to play from local storage of iOS device? If yes, so what step follow for that.

Looking for your reply..

Answer (score 4):

You will only be able to play the HLS content if it's being served over HTTP. So you should run a simple http server in one thread, and then pass the local URL to `MPMoviePlayerController`. The URL will look like `http://localhost:8080/file.m3u8` and the video player will read the stream from the http server you have running in another thread.

Here is a question about running a webserver on iOS that might help you along: [iPhone HTTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485533/iphone-http-server)

Comment: How would you play it in AVPlayer? is it only possible with MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: It works the same with AVPlayer as well, but the question was about using MPMoviePlayerController or UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

You can host the .m3u8 file on local server e.g GCDWebServer. Just create its instance and pass the path of .m3u8 file in that server. Then use the server generated local host path and pass it to your player It will automatically fetch the key and .ts file as per the content written in .m3u8 file.